# Print a web page to PDF and retain links

Tags: printing, pdf

I'm in 18.04 and trying to print a web page to PDF, which works fine if I choose "Print to file" from the print menu. The catch is that there doesn't seem to be a way to preserve the links on the page. I've tried a few different web pages and it doesn't seem to matter -- printing to PDF from the print dialog doesn't retain any links.

I don't see anything I can touch in the settings, and this particular page is only available to logged in users on a Drupal site so I can't just use a command line tool to pull it.

Is there a workable way to print a web page to PDF and retain all the links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using Firefox, this is a [long-standing request](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=454059) (12 years and counting).

There are some alternatives listed in [this Super User post](http://v), some of them being:

- Use some extension to Firefox

  I didn't feel like adding random extensions for this, so I haven't tested any.
- Use `wkhtmltopdf`

  I got some odd font-rendering issues (top half of monospace fonts were cut off). Not sure why. Otherwise the PDF looked good. [One user suggests using `pandoc`](https://superuser.com/a/983282/334516) via LaTeX conversion.

  Probably won't work for authenticated pages.
- Use Chrome/Chromium.

  This is what I ended up doing. It's automateable:

  ```
  google-chrome-stable --headless --disable-gpu --run-all-compositor-stages-before-draw --print-to-pdf=some-file.pdf proto://some-uri
  ```

  You might be able to rely on saved cookies with Chrome to avoid the login issue.

Comment: It didn't even occur to me that this might be specific to Firefox. Chrome works just fine.

Comment: It's not really specific to Firefox. Firefox relies on the system to do the PDF conversion, and that's why it can't really do much about links. Chrome/Chromium has its own mechanism to convert to PDFs. If you tried to use the system print dialogue in Chrome to get a PDF, I'd say the result would be the same as Firefox.

Comment: It seems Firefox devs have updated the backend system used here (cairo), and enabled links in the generated PDF in Firefox 90. But there's no CLI way to do this yet, though (https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1407238).